Why did American Airlines suspend all flights to Israel until April 2025?
According to Israel Hayom, American Airlines suspended flights to Israel until April 2025. That's ~8 months as of the time of writing which is quite a long time!
I know that Israel is bracing for a potential attack from Hezbollah and Iran for assassinations of top military and political leaders and that may engender counter-attack from Israel which might provoke a regional war.
But all of this is still hypothetical at this point. Additionally, the U.S. and other western countries are exerting diplomatic pressures on Iran to either not carry out the attack or limit its scope/size.
My question is, why did American Airlines choose to suspend flights to Israel for that many months? (Note, I can't access that link for some reason; I get 'Access Denied' message)

I'm not sure whether a decision taken by a private company, even within a geopolitical context, can be considered a political question.

I'm able to read the linked article, and it states that American Airlines hasn't explained the decision yet, but also that they had already been suspending flights to Israel ever since the October 7th attack, so this is merely an extension of the existing suspension rather than an entirely new thing.

IDK much about the latest extension, but back in 2023, it seems it was due to pressure from their union, the APA, which put out a statement that flying into a war zone is inadvisable, after Netanyahu declared that Israel is at war. I guess it's a continuation of the same (simple) position that we're seeing. Back then, the Federal Aviation Administration only issued an "extreme caution" statement, but didn't seem to explicitly recommend outright cancellations.
A quick search on Expedia shows that many other companies, including some US ones, don't [presently] follow suit. E.g. "United operated by Lufthansa", "ITA Airways operated by Delta" are some flights to Ben Gurion I could book right now. Interestingly enough, even "American Airlines operated by British Airways", so I guess the restriction only applies to their own aircraft/pilots, not to any sharing deals. (Note that airlines regularly trade slots at airports, particularly due to a "use-it-or-lose-it rule".)
Back in October some 44% of the flights to Tel Aviv got cancelled. I don't know what the figure is now, I wasn't able to find current statistics. During the April [Iranian] attack [period] various companies cancelled flights till May or June. EasyJet seemingly announced the longest one then, till October (this year). Still some 45 out of 150 foreign operators had resumed flights by April 22 (the date of that article).
KLM also cancelled till October 26, invoking the "security situation". Seemingly they did it on Aug 2. That piece also says "KLM's decision follows similar moves by Lufthansa, Delta, United and other airlines in recent days."  I wonder now if Expedia is trying to sell me a seat on a cancelled flight...

And naturally speaking the union was completely wrong and not a single civilian aircraft was harmed, nor did any even come close to being harmed. The union was likely driven by anti-Israeli attitudes rather than a serious risk assessment.

@JonathanReez The risk of harming one might still have been there. With your thinking we could forego a lot of safety measures because nothing happened and people were completely wrong. Maybe nothing happened because fewer airplanes flew there.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution lots of other airlines did a risk assessment and kept on flying, so it's clearly not a controversial position to take. And no, the number of planes has nothing to do with it. Hitting a moving airplane is really hard and requires sophisticated equipment like the Buk missile system which Hamas never had. You have a much better chance of hitting Ben Gurion airport, which never happened.

Lufthansa appears to use a much shorter time frame for these announcements. There's a Google-cached version/snippet that's returned on a search that says "All flights to Tel Aviv, Tehran and Beirut are suspended up to and including August 12." But if you follow the link, their current website page says "All flights to Amman, Beirut, Erbil, Teheran and Tel Aviv are suspended up to and including Wednesday, 21.August." I'd venture a guess they update it weekly.

@JonathanReez: Hezbollah has demonstrated use of the (Iranian) 358 missile which can loiter and kill (high flying) drones. But those are slow, propeller-driven drones like the various Hermes that Hezbollah shot down. Whether the 358 can catch up with a commercial jet is pretty doubtful. (Aside, the Houthis also used the 358 to down some US Reapers etc.)

@JonathanReez: aside to the aside: even though Iran has bombed [some of] the Kurds, the PKK apparently got a hold of a 358 and downed a Turkish drone that way https://www.middleeasteye.net/news/pkk-new-tech-fuels-turkey-suspicions-iran

@JonathanReez: according to DIA [see page 10] the 358 [=Saqr] has a respectable range of 100-150km. https://www.dia.mil/Portals/110/Documents/News/Military_Power_Publications/Iran_Houthi_Final2.pdf It's not inconceivable it could hit a jet on landing or takeoff, if it gets there without being shot down first, of course.

N.B. 150km might be range of 'Saqr-2' https://x.com/IranDefense/status/1705017858877485340 Iranian number designation not known for now.

@timetakesitstoll - I doubt the concern is as much about aerial attacks as it is about the risk to passengers and crew on the ground. Passengers get off and go places; crew go to hotels and sleep while they wait for their next flight. Any risk to Israelis from Iran or Hamas is also a risk to them. Some passengers may even go to Palestine, in which case they may even be at risk from the Israeli military. It is unsurprising that airlines want to avoid all this potential liability.

@Obie2.0 an airline is not responsible for the safety of its passengers once the travel has finished. If you get in a car crash in your way home/to the hotel from the airport, good luck trying to sue the company.

@SJuan76 - But it might be in the case of flight attendants and pilots, who work for the airline. And if I were a corporate lawyer, I wouldn't like to take the risk that a judge would always view transporting tourists to a war zone in quite the same way as transporting them to a peaceful region where they happened to get in an accident. To say nothing of publicity if someone were attacked on a plane on the ground or at the gate.
